# php get key and value from array inside array

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
private $user;
private $location;
private $users = array('user1' => array('John Doe' => 'NYC'),
                       'user2' => array('Jane Doe' => 'NYC'));

function setUser($user) {
  foreach ($users[$user] as $key => $value) {
    $this->user = $key;
    $this->location = $value;
  }
}
```

I want to create methid `setUser($user)` where you pass in user id, and then return the users name and location.

Example of method call:

```
setUser(user1);
```

If the user is set to user1, then return user1 data, if user is set to user2, then return user2 data
But the $user variable isn't set to John Doe in my example.

Comment: Where is $test passed to your function?

Comment: Yes, by nesting loops. It was typo. With $thest I ment $users array. Edited

Comment: I edited the question to bee more understandable

Comment: `foreach($this->users[$user]...`

Comment: Seems a pretty complicated and unmaintainable way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function setUser($user) {
  foreach ($this->users[$user] as $key => $value) {
    $this->user = $key;
    $this->location = $value;
  }
```